# Using Sapper ESM module loader in node: `import *` fails

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, sapper

I wish to use an ES2015 module for a project. Per [the node documentation, I am enabling the `.esm` loader](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/esm.html):

```
~\Code\spa-test $ node --experimental-modules                                                                           (node:8104) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.                                               

> import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';                                                                             Thrown:
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I have also tried:

```
import {middleware} from '@sapper/server';
```

Which fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

How do I make node.js load the `@sapper/server` ESM module?

Comment: Is your goal to go with the `import` or you might consider using `require` too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your code in a file with the extension ".mjs" to mark it as ES6 Module.

In Node.js V12 there is also a commandline switch `"--input-type=module"` which might work in case of interactively using Node.js (REPL).

`'@sapper/server'` is not a legal module path in Node.js. The path of a module filename either has to start with `'.'` or `'..'` and the file extension has to be `'.mjs'`, so a legal import statement would be

```
import * as sapper from './@sapper/server.mjs';
```

When '@sapper' is not a module filename but a package name and the package.json definition contains the '`"type": "module"`', it should also work (I didn't test this, yet).

See also the [documentation of "Node.js V12 ECMAScript Modules"](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) and ["Node.js V10 ECMAScript Modules"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/esm.html)

Comment: Thanks. However using `.mjs` isn't working either. My code is `import * as sapper from './@sapper/server.mjs';`. The error is `Error: Cannot find module '@sapper/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)`

Comment: See updated answer above. It depends if '@sapper' is a Node.js package (with a package.json) or just a directory which contains a ES Module file called server.mjs.

Comment: How does you directory structure look like? Is there a directory "node_modules/@sapper' or is it called "node_modules/sapper"? Is this an ES Module (used via 'import') or a Node.js module (used via 'require()')? Is this module written by you or do you refer to an existing module?

Comment: When using 'sapper', you have a file "my-app/src/node_modules/@sapper" in your project which is referenced in "my-app/src/server.js". I don't know how sapper works, but loading that module works when you do it in the my-app/src directory. Your problem is a sapper specific problem and not a general Node.js module problem.

Comment: you're completely right. I chatted with the Sapper developers on Discord and they helped answer this.

Answer (score 0):

As @michaeldrehner mentioned, this is a Sapper specific issue (I've edited the title to reflect this).

My issue was

- Files in `src` are input for sapper and not designed to be loaded by node directly.
- `npm build` or `sapper build` will rollup sapper *and( server.js into a single bundle. This output is in `**sapper**/build/server/server.js
- That bundle can be loaded by node `node .\__sapper__\build\index.js` without any additional magic - the bundle is transformed into the proper node compatible module format.

Thanks to the Sapper developers on Discord for their help answering this.